# MySQL won't start?

Tags: mysql

when running `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`, it shuts down ok but doesn't start back up.
Running `df -h` i get the following:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          3.6G  1.7G  1.8G  48% /
/dev/root       3.6G  1.7G  1.8G  48% /
devtmpfs        235M     0  235M   0% /dev
tmpfs            49M  220K   49M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            98M     0   98M   0% /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p1   56M   19M   38M  33% /boot
```

I also get this error when running `mysql -u root -p`

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Any ideas? stuck on this for hours...

Comment: The second error is a result of the fact that MySQL is not running. It should be logging any errors generated when it fails to start. Have you checked the error log?

Comment: I'm knocking this down as "Unclear what you're asking" because you're not giving any clue as to ***why*** MySQL is failing to start. If you would like further assistance with this, please update your question to include sufficient detail to allow someone to troubleshoot. See [this Meta topic](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) for some tips.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL is not starting.

To find out why, check MySQL's own error logs, generally located at `/var/log/mysql/error.log`, and the general system log (which should be `/var/log/syslog` on a Debian based system).

Answer (score 1):

What is in your my.cnf file? Typically, this can happen from a misconfiguration in my.cnf. Make sure /var/run/mysqld/ exists and can be read/written too.